# Python IF/ELIF/ELSE statements producing error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been working on a project, and to test If/Elif/Else projects, I wrote a little bit of code to get an idea how it worked. I wrote:

```
opclo = input('>');
if(opclo == 'CLOSED'):
    print "Good night.";
elif(opclo == 'WACKED'):
    print "wacked";
else:
    print "Good morning.";
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 2, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CLOSED' is not defined
```

I am wondering why it does this. I have tried mutliple things, such as removing brackets, adding a `opclo = opclo2` (making line 1's `opclo` into `opclo2`) and adding a array with `"CLOSED"` and `"WACKED"` in it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the semicolons?

Comment: If you completely deleted the `if`/`elif`. you'd still have this exact error.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Python2 so you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

```
opclo = raw_input('>')
if opclo == 'CLOSED':
    print "Good night."
elif opclo == 'WACKED':
    print "wacked"
else:
    print "Good morning."
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

input('>') - for python expressions

raw_input - for strings.

You should use raw_input

Comment: `input` is not for digits, but for python expressions.